# How to add text behind image

Tags: flutter

I want to achive output like below image can any once please help me on this, I have tried by self but not getting same out put below is my code:

```
    Container(
       child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
             child:Image(image: AssetImage('assets/contacts/Facebook.png')
          ),
       ),
       width: 370,
       height: 70,
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(58),
           color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 87, 87),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 ),
```

[Want Something Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucRUy.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stack` widget to put widgets upfrontnof each other

Answer (score 0):

You can use sth like this:

```
Stack(
    children:[
        Text(''),
        Image('src')
    ]
)
```